# C++ Game Design - What Library/API?

Tags: c++, api, 2d

I am currently developing an rpg type game in C++. I have developed a few games in the past but have used heavily inclusive APIs. For this game I am looking into developing it more myself. I still want the graphic and animation functions to be (mainly) implemented using the library. Here is a break down of the game:

- It will be a top down tile-based game when not in battle where the character is free to walk around and speed will be determined by a speed stat
- Once in battle it will be a turn-based battle system with (not completely final) 3 man team on each side
- Some information will be stored online and will be used in the game but that will not need to be checked often

What I am asking is; what would most likely by the best library or API for me to use for this purpose? I have searched and have been able to find a few that I believe may suit my needs but none that have been popular. Perhaps I am looking for something too specific but any help or recommendation would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. Along with a recommendation, a link for a decent tutorial or documentation would be most appreciated.

Comment: 3 man team . . . whoa, that completely changes the library that you should select ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always the popular [libsdl](http://www.libsdl.org/). There are many tutorials for this library online inluding the dedicated

http://www.sdltutorials.com/

You can always use as much or as little of a library's functionality as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at this?

http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/

If you look in the forums, people have written their own compatible libraries for AI, Physics etc etc that they seem to be happy to share.  Also there are lots of compatible tools like this http://www.ambiera.com/coppercube/  and lots of language wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to Caustic's answer, I suggest looking into [Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/). Like [Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/), it is primarily a *rendering engine*, leaving much of the work to be done by yourself. From personal experience, I cannot recommend one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to swear. I believe you should use SFML because it is an all-around nice library for graphics development.